# Composing edges from a square matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I found a couple interesting Project Euler problems (81-83). They all are variations of "find shortest path" through this square matrix.  I'll use Djikstra's Shortest Path algorithm to solve all of them at once. They each have their own weird variations, but that can all be modeled with various edge setups (some problems can only move "right and down"  and others are "up/down/left/right".)

Anyway, I thought I had written a slick way to generalize the edge construction, using a list of "modes" to specify, for a given node, which adjacent nodes I can create edges to.  Fragment of this code is below:

```
def makeGraph(fn="smallMatrix.txt", modes = [(0,1), (0,-1), (-1,0), (1,0)]):
        for row in range(0, len(network)):
            for col in range(0, len(network[row])):
                #create edges
                edgesFromNewNode = []
                for mode in modes:
                    try:
                        #newEdge = ( edgeLength, (destination row, col)  )
                        newEdge = (    network[row+mode[0]][col+mode[1]], ( row+mode[0] , col+mode[1] ) )
                        edgesFromNewNode.append(newEdge)
                    except IndexError:
                        pass
                edgeCatalog[(row, col)] = edgesFromNewNode
```

So I couldn't understand why node (0,0) (the upper left node) had four edges -- it should have only two valid ones (1,0) and (0,1).  Then I realized,  When I apply the mode masks to (0,0), I get things like (0,-1) and (-1,0), which AREN'T index errors -- they're saying use the end of the list.

I can solve this stuff with a bunch of gross if-then-else cases when dealing with row=0 or col=0, but it's gross.  I was hoping for a more pythonic approach than that.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Say in general the grid size is **m** rows by **n** columns and you can move to any valid adjacent cell from a cell.Then you can use the direction arrays ( similar to your mode )

```
dx[4]={0,-1,0,1} // movement in rows
dy[4]={-1,0,1,0} // movement in columns
```

Now suppose you are at cell **x,y** and you want to go to their valid adjacent cells

```
 int valid(int i,int j)
 {
    if(i>=0&&i<m&&j>=0&&j<n)return 1;
    return 0;
 }

 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
     new_x=dx[i]+x;
     new_y=dy[i]+y;
     if( valid(new_x,new_y) )
     {
         /* new_x,new_y is valid adjacent cell
            do whatever you want to process with it  */
     }
 }
```

It is more clean this way i suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Be explicit.  The following variant is not really longer and arguably clearer than `try... except IndexError:`

```
if 0 <= row+mode[0] < len(network):
    if 0 <= col+mode[1] < len(network[row]):
        newEdge = (...)
        edgesFromNewNode.append(newEdge)
```